# Composing concat and map to get concatMap: why the f?

Tags: haskell

Those are my first explorations in Haskell, so pardon me if it should be obvious.

I have been playing all afternoon with Haskell, sifting through the tutorial [99 questions on HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions), using my own list type (typical Cons). I've added "obvious" functions as I went on, and I have tried to make them as concise as possible (employing point-free notation whenever possible)

The 12th problem is about decoding a run-length encoded list, that is:

```
> decode [Multiple 5 'a', Single 'b', Multiple 2 'c']
"aaaaabcc"
```

And I thought about using `map` to decode each element, then `concat` the result (thanks Google on this), and finally remembered that I had seen something like `concatMap` in my readings, which GHCi quickly confirmed:

```
> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
> :t concat
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
> :t concatMap
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It looked like it would be obvious to reimplement `concatMap`:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap = concat . map
```

Except that GHCi quite complains:

```
List.hs:110:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a] -> [b]'
                with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: [[a0]] -> [a] -> [b]
      Actual type: [[a0]] -> [[a0]]
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `concat'
    In the expression: concat . map
```

I could not figure it out, so I looked up on the web, and the definition referenced in Prelude is actually:

```
concatMap f = concat . map f
```

And I don't quite understand why this f is necessary, since it's type is obviously `a -> [b]` as specified by the signature...

So why is `f` necessary here ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with the standard definition,

```
concat . map f 
 ≡ concat . (map f)
 ≡ \x -> concat ((map f) x)
```

Your first definition gives you:

```
(concat . map) f
 ≡ (\x -> concat (map x)) f
 ≡ concat (map f)
```

which doesn't type check because `(map f) :: [a] -> [b]`, while `concat` takes `[[a]]`, a list of lists.

Note the particular error message shown in the question doesn't describe the above type-check failure. The given message arises from declaring the return type `concatMap` as `[a] -> [b]`, which isn't reconcilable with `[a0]`, the return type of `concat`. If you leave off the type signature, the response is:

> ```
>     Couldn't match type ‘[a1] -> [b]’ with ‘[[a]]’
>     Expected type: (a1 -> b) -> [[a]]
>       Actual type: (a1 -> b) -> [a1] -> [b]
>     Relevant bindings include
>       concatMap :: (a1 -> b) -> [a] (bound at :49:5)
>     Probable cause: ‘map’ is applied to too few arguments
>     In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map’
>     In the expression: concat . map
> ```

Here, the type error occurs when reconciling the return type of `map` with the argument type of `concat`. It turns out this case is more useful for debugging as it contains a hint why the type check failed.

Comment: Ah! Is it fair to say that functions on the right-hand side of `.` should expect a single argument ? (not 2 like `map` before it was curried ?)  Also, is there some trick to write this in point free style ?

Comment: @Matthiew Every function in Haskell accepts a single argument. For example, `map` accepts a function and returns a function `g = map f` which, in its turn, accepts a list and returns an element. Also, remember an important thing: function application binds tighter than any operator, it helps a lot to figure things out. I don't know how to write this point free.

Comment: it's definitely a strange journey I am embarking upon :) `replicateList :: Int -> List a -> List a` (Problem 15, altered) can be written point free as `replicateList = concatMap . replicate` and the two arguments are passed, no typechecking issue.

Comment: @Matthieu That's because it has a different order of application. If you write it with all arguments, then `replicateList n xs = concatMap (replicate n) xs`, but in your example `concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)`. The 'bracket structure' is different.

Comment: Okay,I think I am going to run in a number of precedence issue before I got this right. The "write all arguments" will come in handy, thank you!

Comment: The answer as it stands is wrong: `(concat . map) f = concat (map f)` which doesn't typecheck since `map f` is not a list.

Comment: Point-free: `concatMap = (concat .) . map`