# What is the difference between mapcat in Clojure and concatmap in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, clojure, concatenation, flatmap

In Clojure you have a function called [mapcat](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat) in Clojure, which bears some similarity to [flatmap in Scala](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/). It is [used to map a function to a list](http://clojurian.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/beware-of-mapcat.html) and return a list.

In Haskell we have a function [ConcatMap](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=concatMap) which in name [seems quite similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524683/composing-concat-and-map-to-get-concatmap-why-the-f).

My question is - **what is the difference between mapcat in Clojure and concatmap in Haskell?**

Comment: Why do you think they are different?

Comment: Because mapcat in Clojure and flatmap in Scala are different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363205/what-are-the-differences-between-mapcat-in-clojure-and-flatmap-in-scala-in-terms

Comment: `flatMap` in Scala is the general name for monadic bind, which is `>>=` in Haskell.  On the other hand `concatMap` is `>>=` specialised to the `[]` monad.

Comment: So you're saying that the Clojure function and the Haskell function are similar, apart from the underlying differences in the data structures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`concatMap` in Haskell has the type `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]` while Clojure's `mapcat`, if it were to have any type at all, would have to be much more complex. At first approximation, we could write

```
mapcat :: (Collection c, Collection c') => (a -> c' b) -> c a -> [b]
```

Although, technically `mapCat` inherits `map`'s dynamic argument list and thus cannot be typed in Haskell at all, but if it could it might look like

```
mapcat :: (forall c . Collection c => a -> ... -> c b) 
       -> [forall c . Collection c => c a]
       -> [b]
```

which emphasizes how dynamic `mapCat` could be, though still less dynamic than it actually is. That said, if we promise to just pass one lazy seq into `mapcat` then it's identical to `concatMap` and has almost exactly identical code

```
concatMap f s = concat (map f s)

(defn mapcat [f coll] (concat (map f coll)))
```

That said, in Haskell nobody uses `concatMap`, they use `(>>=)` (or list comprehensions which can be translated to `(>>=)` if desired).

```
-- flipped for consistency
flip (>>=) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

It turns out that `(>>=)` is still less polymorphic on input than `mapcat`, but `(>>=)` is also output polymorphic. This allows it to have a great deal more semantic variety. You're not always draining values from collections, zipping the answers into a result list, and then gluing those results together. You might instead be passing a continuation function into a non-deterministic parallel orchestration process. Or sequencing parsers where the second depends on output from the first. Or propagating a stateful environment.

Comment: I was very interested to see that. I'm not quite sure still how to read multi-arity type annotations—does it allow for individually varying inputs to the map function?

Comment: The `t ... b` is a template for a sequence of types. It handles any legal arity of `mapcat` such that the function argument matches the number of arguments to `mapcat`. The paper describing this research is called "Practical Variable-Arity Polymorphism".

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a read. I'm currently implementing a system like this at work.

Answer (score 1):

`mapcat` only operates on sequences, and always returns a lazy-seq.

Comment: "and always returns a lazy-seq" That's not a difference, since `concatMap` also returns a lazy list.

Comment: I don't know Haskell. I'm just describing mapcat in Clojure.